# reemplazar una hoja de excel con un archivo que sale desde R

Tags: r

Estoy tratando de exportar un archivo de R en formato xlsx con la funcion:

```
write.xlsx(df,"archivoexistente.xlsx", sheetname = "nuevoarchivo", append = TRUE)
```

pero me genera el siguiente error:

> Error in .jnew("java/io/FileInputStream", path.expand(file)) : Java
> Exception <no description because toString()
> failed>.jnew("java/io/FileInputStream",
> path.expand(file))new("jobjRef", jobj = <pointer: 0x00000112394988d8>,
> jclass = "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError")

alguien podría por favor orientarme de que se debe hacer o si hay otra manera de reemplazar el archivo, mil gracias.

el tamaño del DF es: 8796 observaciones 12 Variables, 895584 bytes, pero con cualquier archivo me aparece el mismo mensaje

Comment: Hola Ivan, existen dos funciones  `write.xlsx` en r. Una en el paquete `xlsx` y otra en el paquete `openxlsx`. ¿Cual usas tu? En mi caso me gusta más el paquete `openxlsx`, en este paquete guarde un excel rápidamente. También probe `xlsx`, y este tarde mucho tiempo corriendo hasta que al final me lanzo un error.

Comment: Roger buenas noches, utilizo ambos pero para poder guardar con password no me funciona openxlsx por esto utilizo wtrite.xlsx

Comment: Ivan tienes razón `openxlsx` no me guardo con contraseña. Continuare revisando el problema

Comment: Ivan prueba instalar de nuevo el paquete `xlsx` yo lo  hice y me funciono sin error y guardo con contraseña. La version que instalo fue 0.6.4.2

Comment: Rolando, ese paquete me funciono perfecto para el tema de la contraseña sin embargo para utilizar la funcion append me sale el error de la consulta